# 3.1.x SiteNotFoundException

Tags: craft3

Not sure if this is related to Craft 3.1.x, but since I ran that update this afternoon, I can't update details of my Site anymore. If I go to Settings > Sites and try to update anything in there (like changing @siteUrl to @web), I get this error:

```
Getting unknown property: craft\records\SiteGroup::craft\errors\SiteNotFoundException
```

[image]

Comment: I've just had this happen on another site so I'm posting a bug report: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/3687